# How do I update profile name in DISQUS account?

Tags: account-management, profile, disqus

I have logged in to DISQUS via a Google account for providing comments. I would like to change my profile name, but I can’t. I've changed my name in Google account but it’s not reflecting in DISQUS. I don’t have a DISQUS ID; I use the Google ID.